# Isn't got anyway to insert by descending?

Tags: php, mysql

What I need to insert is by descending record.

my code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO entertainment VALUES ('','$result','$date')");
```

result:

```
id  result  date
1   a       26/9/2011
2   b       25/9/2011 
3   c       24/9/2011
```

What I want is:

```
id  result  date
1   c       24/9/2011
2   b       25/9/2011 
3   a       26/9/2011
```

Isn't possible do it ?

here is my full code, what i doing now i rss grabbing,once i grab all the result i will insert the result to my database:

```
     $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
        $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($content);          
            foreach($xml->channel->item as $entry){ 

                $title = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($entry->title));
                $description = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($entry->description));   
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO entertainment VALUES ('','$entry->pubDate','$title','$description')"); 
                }
```

Comment: Sure, just insert the values in a different order. That said, optimally the id shouldn't be used to order the records, just to identify them.

Comment: do you call mysql_query in a loop? Then you can revert the loop to achive what you want. Show some more code and we can answer it more correctly

Comment: It shouldn't matter what order the values are inserted, that is what `SELECT ... ORDER BY ...` statements are for. I think you need to examine your application logic rather than how you are inserting the data.

Comment: Questions like these should be ignored and closed.. not only is the idea terrible, I can also hear grammar police marching up someone's door steps.

Answer (score 4):

### No.

This is a **really bad idea**. The (autoincrement) ID column should not be significant for your data - so you really shouldn't care about its value.

Furthermore, how would MySQL know where to start from? If you insert three, it should start from 3 and count to 1, but what if you insert more later?

Instead of changing the order while inserting, you should probably **change  the query that reads the data later**. Have that query return the data really the way you want it.

```
SELECT *
FROM entertainment
ORDER BY result DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, insert the data in any way, and use `SELECT * FROM entertainment ORDER BY date Desc`  at the time of retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO orders (id  result  date) select id  result  date from tablename order by id desc